# Non consistent bug - debugger not starting in VS code

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

- VSCode Version: 1.13.1
- OS Version: Windows 10

Steps to Reproduce:

1. Open a node project
2. Press F5 or Click play button from debugger pane

Does this issue occur when all extensions are disabled?: Yes

A few times I have noticed that the debugger does not start in Visual Studio. Anyone know any fix to this?

Comment: I have similar issues on other editors/IDEs in Windows too. But, in the spirit of helpfulness, is the indexing service running at this time?

Comment: @Zlatko I'm not sure because I never heard about an indexing service.

Comment: Oh, IDEs will occassionally (like, after restart) and periodically rescan all the files, to pick up all the function names and variables etc, so it can help you with your work. Sometimes this disables other functionalities temporarily. Should not disable debugging, but maybe just the editor is overwhelmed at that point.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a `launch.json` file? It should be at `.vscode/launch.json`
With the following format:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Program",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/myscript.js"
        }
    ]
}
```

You can find more information here: https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/debugging

Comment: I have a launch.json file with the content you posted. What shall be done with this file?

Comment: Now you can start debugging, and Visual Studio Code should run the `myscript.js` in debug mode. If you generate the `myscript.js` (with webpack or similar) you should generate a `myscript.js.map` file also.

Comment: The file was there since the beginning, I believe there is some other issue